# how to disable other items in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a list view, this setup is like the guess that logo game where you can't proceed with the next level until you finish the level before that. I have been searching all night already, I found examples and questions about disabling other items in listview but I cannot find the specific answer that I can use in my problem. Now I am asking. **how to disable other items in listview?** and enable them if the level before them is complete, I'm also trying to achieve this by getting the "level status" from sqlite database.

This is the jave code extends ListActivity:

```
static final String[] LEVELS = new String[] { "Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3",
        "Level 4", "Level 5", "Level 6", "Level 7", "Level 8", "Level 9", "Level 10" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_play, LEVELS));

        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        switch(position) {          
                        case 0:
                            Intent lvlOne = new Intent(".LevelOneActivity");
                            startActivity(lvlOne);                          
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent lvlTwo = new Intent(".LevelTwoActivity");
                            startActivity(lvlTwo);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should just make easy class which will hold  your level and class which it should start

```
public class ListItemInfo
{
String mActivityToStart;
int mLevel
}
```

then just add a TAG to each of list items which you will hold in adapter when creating a view

after that

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{               
if (#DB GET UNLOCKED LVL) >= ((ListItemInfo)v.getTag()).mActivityToStart)
 {
  Intent lvlOne = new Intent(getContext(), ((ListItemInfo)v.getTag()).mLevel);
                            startActivity(lvlOne);   
 }
});
```